# Using @State variable does not work for changing view state in Body from child view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's say in my iOS SwiftUI app there is a simple ContentView with two views inside.

The reference to ContentView is available to other parts of code.

From there the user wants to determine which of the two views are displayed, that is, one, none or both.

That code is something like

```
contentViewReference.setView1Visible(view1Visible:true) //or false
```

Here's the ContentView

```
struct ViewsState
{
    var view1Visible:Bool
    var view2Visible:Bool
    init(view1Visible:Bool,view2Visible:Bool)
       {
          self.view1Visible=view1Visible
          self.view2Visible=view2Visible
       }
 }

struct ContentView: View 
{ 
    @State private var viewsState:ViewsState=ViewsState(view1Visible:true,view2Visible:false)

    
    public func setView1Visible(view1Visible:Bool)
        {
          viewsState.view1Visible=view1Visible
        }

    public func setView2Visible(view2Visible:Bool)
        {
          viewsState.view2Visible=view2Visible
        }

    var body: some View 
    {
        if (viewsState.view1Visible) {View1}
        if (viewsState.view1Visible) {View2}
    }
}
```

but the views' visibility does never change, why?

I do not think I need Binding because the state "truth" is inside ContentView, but it is assigned through public funcs.

There is no parent View, the toggling code indeed is inside a menu that is part of View1.

But when calling

```
setView1Visible(view1Visible:false)
```

for example, there is no effect, View1 does not become hidden.

This is just a snippet of code. Real ContentView is slightly more elaborate, but the question does not change.

Comment: Hi P5Music, is the visibility of the views depending on two separate conditions, or is the visibility depending on one condition? What I want to know is is either one visible or can both be visible or not be visible? Secondly, what determines the visibility? Is it a user tap or another kind of condition?

Comment: @MacUserT In the real app I use this as a sort of navigation system, so yes, ideally when View1 is hid, View2 is then made visible. I know it is experimental but I need to know how it works, there is no reason it does not work, even as an exercise.

Comment: `@State` should be uppercase

Comment: It is likely asking for an `else` too some view needs to be in the `body` if both are `false`

Comment: Also, you can't access methods inside the `View` from another `View`, `class`, `struct`  ideally user's will access your `ViewState` not the `ContentView` directly

Comment: @lorem ipsum Do not worry about the reference, it works, just tell me how to have this working. The funcs are called, I see it also because I put some print() instructions inside, just the state does not change.

Comment: SwiftUI is all about the references it does matter. Referencing the `ContentView` will not work because it is not publishing changes. `@State` only works when changes are made within the `View` `body` per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state). Not when you call a method in a `View` from somewhere else.

Comment: SwiftUI `View`s do not work like other `struct`s or `class`es you can't have references in other places and expect to access the contents as usual

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewsState: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var view1Visible:Bool
    @Published var view2Visible:Bool
    init(view1Visible:Bool,view2Visible:Bool)
    {
        self.view1Visible=view1Visible
        self.view2Visible=view2Visible
    }
    public func setView1Visible(view1Visible:Bool)
    {
        self.view1Visible = view1Visible
        view2Visible = !view1Visible
    }
    
    public func setView2Visible(view2Visible:Bool)
    {
        self.view2Visible = view2Visible
        view1Visible = !view2Visible
    }
}

struct ViewStateView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewsState: ViewsState = ViewsState(view1Visible:true,view2Visible:false)

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack{
            if (viewsState.view1Visible) {Text("View1")}
            if (viewsState.view2Visible) {Text("View2")}
            SomeOtherView().environmentObject(viewsState)
        }
    }
}
struct SomeOtherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewsState: ViewsState
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack{
            Text("SomeOtherView")
            Button("change state view 1", action: {
                viewsState.setView1Visible(view1Visible:false)
            })
            Button("change state view 2", action: {
                viewsState.setView2Visible(view2Visible:false)
            })
        }
        
    }
}
struct ViewStateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewStateView()
    }
```

Comment: I get "No ObservableObject of type ViewsState found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ViewsState may be missing as an ancestor of this view" whatever method I use to "create" and inject that object in the Views, starting with the ContentView and so on. What is the solution to have a "live" Observable and State object all over the Views hierarchy?

Comment: You have to add this when you initiate the view .environmentObject() look at the SomeOtherView initializing in the body

Comment: I have some views, one is called mainView but it is among the others inside ContentView, but it wants a StateObject of itself, at runtime it says that a new instance will be created every time, but if I use environmentObject instead, it says that there is no observable object in the ancestor.

Comment: The view that is saying that need the environmentObject modifier upon initialization. You have to pass it down the line. There are certain situations like sheets where it doesn’t pass down automatically. This same error has been asked several times in SO

Comment: I ensure that my code resembles yours, just in the mainView's body it has a func call returning EmptyView that is used to set some viewsState members so that they are used immediately after, below. The func just set one subview visible, the other hidden.

Comment: The solution was injecting the observable object directly in the init of MainView (and other views) instead of calling .environmentObject(object), and assigning it to an ObservableObject instead of EnvironmentObject. No delays in setting that special object this way. It works

Answer (score 0):

@P5music, there is not enough code to replicate your issue and investigate properly.
Also I don't know how you get:

```
   contentViewReference.setView1Visible(view1Visible:true)
```

Here are some observations regarding your code.

```
    @State private var viewsState:ViewsState(view1Visible:true,view2Visible:false)
```

should be

```
    @State var viewsState = ViewsState(view1Visible:true,view2Visible:false)
```

also you probably want:

```
    var body: some View 
{
    if (viewsState.view1Visible) {View1}
    if (viewsState.view2Visible) {View2}  // <--- here 
}
```

In addition, "...determine which of the two views are displayed", this means that every time you set
"view1Visible" to some value, at the same time you also need to set "view2Visible" to the opposite.

Comment: Don't forget the uppercase `@State`

Comment: yes thanks, I've just updated the answer/comment.

Comment: @workingdog It is not important now which view is visible or not, just this should be working. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "contentViewReference.setView1Visible(view1Visible:true)" works, the following
test code seems to work:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ViewsState{
    var view1Visible:Bool
    var view2Visible:Bool
    init(view1Visible:Bool, view2Visible:Bool){
        self.view1Visible = view1Visible
        self.view2Visible = view2Visible
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewsState = ViewsState(view1Visible:true, view2Visible:false)
    
    public func setView1Visible(view1Visible:Bool){
        viewsState.view1Visible = view1Visible
        viewsState.view2Visible = !view1Visible
    }
    
    public func setView2Visible(view2Visible:Bool){
        viewsState.view2Visible = view2Visible
        viewsState.view1Visible = !view2Visible
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("change view") {
                if viewsState.view1Visible {
                    setView1Visible(view1Visible: false)
                } else {
                    setView1Visible(view1Visible: true)
                }
            }
            if (viewsState.view1Visible) {View1()}
            if (viewsState.view2Visible) {View2()}
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View1")
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View2")
    }
}
```