# SwiftUI Change Observed Object From Another View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an observed object in my ContentView which contains tabviews.

```
class GlobalValue: ObservableObject {
  @Published var stringValue = ""
  @Published var intValue = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var globalValue = GlobalValue()
}
```

From one of the tabs I need to change ContentView's observed object value.

```
ContentView().globalValue.intValue=25
```

It is not changing the value. How can I change that observed object value? thanks...

Comment: This one ```ContentView()``` you're creating a new object of view. You have to use Environment objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using @State variable does not work for changing view state in Body from child view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68055953/using-state-variable-does-not-work-for-changing-view-state-in-body-from-child-v)

Comment: You can take reference from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940114/14733292 see second approch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is changing the value. The problem is you are instantiating an instance of GlobalValue locally in your struct. It has no life outside of the struct. I you want to use an `Observable Object` as a global store like that, you need to create it once and use that instance.

The easiest way to do this is to add
`static let shared = GlobalValue()` in your class, and in your struct use `globalValue = GlobalValue.shared` which essentially gives you a singleton. You will have one instance that all the views can read and write to.